# How to get hidden cell value of selected row from a DataTable using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have to select row and try to get the value of `id="selectSeqNumber20190627114037938"`, `id="20190627114037938-TotalSt"` and `id="20190627114037938-PassSt"`.
I am able to get expected values, but if I change the page (already row was selected on other page) of data table then not able to get values.

Here I will select more than one row and then submit the form.

```
<tr class="odd" role="row">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkProgram" class="chk" id="chkselect25" value="20190627114037938";">
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="runId20190627114037938">20190627114037938</div>
        </td>
        <td class="hidden">
            <div class="float-label-control" style="padding:2px;">
                <select id="selectSeqNumber20190627114037938" class="form-control" style="display: block;">
                    <option value="ALL" selected="selected">ALL</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="testcaseRunName20190627114037938">Test</div>
        </td>
        <td class="hidden">
            <div>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li>
                        <a class="label label-info row-stat-badge" title="Total">
                            <strong id="20190627114037938-TotalSt">106</strong>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="label label-success row-stat-badge" title="Pass">
                            <strong id="20190627114037938-PassSt">5</strong>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="excutedBy20190627114037938">adminuseruser</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

JS code:

```
     // All IDs are dynamically generated
     $(dropId).val();
     $('#firstTotal').text($("#"+firstRunId+"-Total"+fTFlag).text());
     $('#firstPass').text($("#"+firstRunId+"-Pass"+fTFlag).text());
```

Comment: No jQuery code that has relation to DataTables; no even `<table>` tag inside HTML sample; no way to find out the way you implement selection... so I had to flag this question 'too broad'

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTables [`$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) API method that performs jQuery selection action on the full table.

For example:

```
$('#firstTotal').text
   $('#example').DataTable().$("#"+firstRunId+"-Total"+fTFlag).text()
);
```

where `example` is ID of your table.

See [jQuery DataTables: How to submit all pages form data](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-submit-all-pages-form-data/) for more information on submitting data from all pages in a table powered by jQuery DataTables.

Comment: It's working for only the current page, but not able to fetch data of n'th page of the datatable.

Comment: @objectif, Datatable `$()` is different from jQuery `$()` method because it allows to access elements from all pages, not just current page. Try `console.log($('#example').DataTable().$('input,select,textarea').serializeArray())` and you will see data from form elements all pages, where `example` is ID of your table.

Comment: Thank you for help. I got output by using below code.              `var allPages1 = $('#myItem1').dataTable().fnGetNodes();`   `$('#firstTotal').text($('td:eq(4) #'+firstRunId+'-Total'+fTFlag+'', allPages1).text());`